# storing the transformed xml into xml file

Tags: php, xml

i have transformed xml ,how can i save this(transformed xml) in xml file(data.xml)using php

my php file is:

```
<?php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
$xmlDoc->load("products.xml");
$xslDoc = new DomDocument;
$xslDoc->load("product.xsl");
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xslDoc);
$strxml= $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);
echo ($strxml);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://php.net/fopen and http://php.net/fwrite

In short:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('data.xml', 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $xml);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML String can be parse using the following function.

`$convertedXML = simplexml_load_string($strXml);`

It can be saved using

```
$convertedXML->saveXML("member.xml");
```

Cheers.